# Array is not rendering inside the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am passing an array by using the Context API that contains details of the employees. When I consume the array in the Employee.js component and trying to render each of the employees using the map method but those values of the array are only displayed in the console and it is not rendering with the JSX.

### data.js

```
export const employees=[
    {
        id:1001,
        name: "Nafaz Benzema",
        salary: 67000,
      
    },
    {
        id:1002,
        name: "Doto Kama",
        salary: 23000,
      
    },
    {
        id:1003,
        name: "Chopa Malli",
        salary: 14000,
        
    }
];
```

### context.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {employees,detailProduct,storeProducts} from './data'

const EmployeeContext=React.createContext();

class EmployeeProvider extends Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            employees:employees
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <EmployeeContext.Provider value={{...this.state}}>
               {this.props.children}
            </EmployeeContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

const EmployeeConsumer=EmployeeContext.Consumer;

export {EmployeeContext,EmployeeProvider,EmployeeConsumer};
```

### Employee.js

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import {EmployeeConsumer} from '../context'
import EmpDisplay from './EmpDisplay';

class Employee extends Component {

    render() {
  
        return (
            <div>
                <EmployeeConsumer>
                    {
                 
                      value=>{
                           value.employees.map(emp=>(
                              <div className="employees">
                        {console.log(emp)}// working
                      <h2>Id : {emp.id}</h2>    //not rendering
                      <h2>Name : {emp.name}</h2> //not rendering
                     <h2>Salary : {emp.salary}</h2> //not rendering
      
                         </div>
                           ));
                      }
                        
                    }
                </EmployeeConsumer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Employee;
```

Comment: You are not returning from the `value => {` anonymous function. Either replace the `{}` with `()` to make it an implicit return, or manually return the result of the map with `return`.

Comment: @Brain Thompson Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot return:

```js
Employee.js
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import {EmployeeConsumer} from '../context'
import EmpDisplay from './EmpDisplay';

class Employee extends Component {

    render() {
  
        return (
            <div>
                <EmployeeConsumer>
                    {
                 
                      value=>{
                           value.employees.map(emp=>{
                              return 
                              <div className="employees">
                        {console.log(emp)}// working
                      <h2>Id : {emp.id}</h2>    //not rendering
                      <h2>Name : {emp.name}</h2> //not rendering
                     <h2>Salary : {emp.salary}</h2> //not rendering
      
                         </div>
                           });
                      }
                        
                    }
                </EmployeeConsumer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several "intresting" places in your example.

1. `<EmployeeContext.Provider value={{...this.state}}>`

Are you sure about state clone? value is recomputed on each render.
Please take a look at official docs https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats

It is better to pass `this.state` as is.

2. `class Employee extends Component { render() {`

It looks like functional component.

3. And finally. The exact problem:

```
<EmployeeConsumer>{value => { ... }}</EmployeeConsumer>
```

In your original example, curly braces stand for a code block and returns `undefined` ignoring `.map` expression

Use `()` instead to explicitly declare an expression:

```
<EmployeeConsumer>{value => (...)}</EmployeeConsumer>
```